# React detect click on polygon in an svg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to migrate an app to React. The app interacts with svgs. The svgs are made of polygons, roughly `<svg><polygon /> <polygon />... </svg>`, and the user can click on each polygon.

In the pure JS version, I was able to add eventLister to each polygon by getElementById to detect clicks on different polygons. But I haven't found anything related to handle such thing in React.

Sorry I don't have anything more concrete because I don't know where to start on this. Any general suggestion?

Comment: have you tried `onClick` event ?

Comment: umm is there a way to convert svg into react components so I can add onclick events to them? I have a lot of svgs, do I need to create a component for each of them or I can import them into a component somehow? If I just import the file, I'm not able to access the polygons...

Comment: I think this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg-polygon package will help you.